# how to create a json object in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to create a JSON object inside a for loop using javascript. I am expecting an result something like this:

```
{
   "array":[
      {
         "value1":"value",
         "value2":"value"
      },
      {
         "value1":"value",
         "value2":"value"
      }
   ]
}
```

Can somebody help me on how to achieve this result in javascript ?

Comment: Just use normal objects to create the structure and use `JSON.stringify` at the end to convert it to JSON. Don't build JSON manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of creating the JSON in the for-loop, create a regular JavaScript object using your for-loops and use JSON.stringify(myObject) to create the JSON.

```
var myObject = {};

for(...) {
   myObject.property = 'newValue';
   myObject.anotherProp = [];
   for(...) {
       myObject.anotherProp.push('somethingElse');
    }
}

var json = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent code in typescript? In typescript I get the error `error TS2339: Property 'someproperty' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Answer (score 3):

```
var loop = [];

for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++){
 loop.push({value1: "value_a_" + x , value2: "value_b_" + x});
}

JSON.stringify({array: loop});
```

Answer (score 1):

This code produces what you need:

```
var result = {"array": []};


for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    var valueDict = {};
    for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        valueDict["value" + (j+1).toString()] = "value";
    }
    result["array"].push(valueDict);
}
```

It uses the [push function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add items to the list, and the [indexer [] notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Indexing_object_properties) notation to modify the entries on the object prototype.

Hope it helps,